# Run public python http.server on Plesk

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, plesk

I have a script that runs with `python3 -m http.server 8080` locally without issues on `http://localhost:8080`

I wanted to make it live on my web server running Plesk/Ubuntu.

First, I installed python3 via SSH and tried to run the same and it returns:
`View in browser: http://localhost:8080` however, nothing happens when trying `http://example.com:8080` in browser (just times out).

Also tried to enable the Plesk module by installing `apt install libapache2-mod-python` and checking the Python box in "Hosting Settings" for that domain.

[image]

Tried with `python3 -m http.server --bind 127.0.0.1 8080` and `python3 -m http.server --bind example.com 8080` to no avail.

Tried setting up <VirtualHost> but figured it won't help since that's apache...

Any ideas how to make the python server visible from outside on port 8080 with Plesk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I needed to do is add port 8080 to Plesk firewall.

`Tools & Settings > Firewall > Modify Plesk Firewall Rules > Add Custom Rule`

[image]

Don't forget to apply changes!
[image]